# Drupal Services JSON response format processing with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, drupal-7

I have a Drupal web service that returns a JSON response in the following format.  I can easily access top level notes e.g. title.  However, I also need to access the value under body.  I can get body.und but not body.und.value.   How do I do that?  Also the HTML tags are showing as text and I can see all the slashes getting printing in my Angular View.

**Update:**  I have been able to get the the value of the body by using $scope.body
= myresponse.data.body.und[0].value;

Now the only problem is how to process HTML in the body.  My Angular framework which is Ionic is showing all the HTML tags e.g. p li etc instead of formatting them.

{"vid":"37","uid":"1","title":"Terms of Use","log":"","status":"1","comment":"1","promote":"0","sticky":"0","nid":"37","type":"page","language":"und","created":"1395878580","changed":"1501982359","tnid":"0","translate":"0","revision_timestamp":"1501982359","revision_uid":"1","body":{"und":[{"value":"

THESE TERMS OF USE (\"TOU\") ARE A LEGAL CONTRACT BETWEEN YOU (\"USER\") AND

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in angular 2?

Comment: No Angular 1.  To support Angular 2 I will need to rewrite the app and I dont' have time for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope.body = myresponse.data.body.und[0].value; helped me get access to the value of the body of the node.

ng-bind-html="body" helped me get access to the body of the HTML.